# Creating user creates unidentified child with same information in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a user in firebase with some extra details. I user firebase's createUserWithEmailAndPassword and then I add the other details under a child with the same authentication id that the function generates. However, when I do this, it also generates a child name "undefined" with the same user's information.

[image: Picture of my database]

Here is the code:

```js
async register(user: User) {
    var id : string;
    try {
      //uses Firebase's Authentication Services to store email and password
      const result = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log('uid',response.uid)
        id=response.uid;
      }

    ).catch(function(error) {
          //Handle error
      });
      console.log(result);
    }
    catch {error => {
      console.log("Error registering user",error);
    }}
    //creates user node with user's information
    console.log(id);
      this.user.type = "customer"
      firebase.database().ref().child(`User/${id}`).set(this.user);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code that depends on the newly created user profile, should be inside the callback that is invoked once that user is created. So:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
  .then(response => {
    id=response.uid;
    //creates user node with user's information
    this.user.type = "customer"
    firebase.database().ref().child(`User/${id}`).set(this.user);
  });
}).catch {error => {
  console.log("Error registering user",error);
}}
```